# How to update database value in django on a button click

Tags: django

I have a template that contains one search button (this is for filtering the details based on option choose in the select) and a Next button (this is to move to next tab).

When the template loads for then i will search for projects from the select list and the result will be displayed in a table - which is working for me.

After the result is displayed in the table, i will select a row (through radio button) from that table and click on Next button to move to next tab. Here when i click the Next button i want to update some values in the django database but not able to achieve this. Can some one help me?

My View:

```
def form(request):
    projects = CreateProjects.objects.filter(Status=True)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        selectproject = request.POST.get('selectproject')
        searchprojlist = ListProjDetails.objects.filter(Project=selectproject)
        return render(request,'form.html',{'projects':projects,'lists': searchprojlist})
    elif request.POST.get('tab1btn','') == 'nxttab':
        selval = ListProjDetails.objects.get(id=1)
        selval.Selected = True
        selval.LockedUser = request.user
        selval.save()
    else:
        lists = ListProjDetails.objects.all()
        return render(request,'form.html',{'projects':projects})
```

First If POST is working correctly, trouble is with the 2nd IF (2nd button). I have swapped the 2nd IF to be called fresh after the else statement but not working either.

I have passed id=1 for testing purpose only

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C56Zd.jpg)

I have added the image for better understanding, basically when the template loads select project from the list and `Search` and then choose one from the output and press `next` that moves to next tab by updating values like `select` to `True` and `Locked User` to `current user`.

My view as explained before.

My Javascript:

```
$(function(){
    $('#nexttab').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        if(document.getElementById('selectradio').checked){
              $('#tabs a[href="#tab2"]').tab('show');
        }
    });
})
```

Template:

```
<form method="POST">
                            {% csrf_token %}
                            <div class="row ml-auto">
                                <select class="custom-select mb-4 ml-2" name="selectproject" style="width: 30em;">
                                    <option selected>Choose...</option>
                                    {% for projects in projects %}
                                    <option>{{ projects.ProjName}}</option>
                                    {% endfor %}
                                </select>
                                <div class="ml-4">
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Search">Search</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            
                            <table class="table">
                                <thead class="thead-light">
                                    <tr>
                                        <th scope="col" class="text-center">S.No.</th>
                                        <th scope="col" class="text-center">Project Name</th>
                                        <th scope="col" class="text-center">Doc</th>
                                        <th scope="col" class="text-center">Target Date</th>
                                        <th scope="col" class="text-center">Docnum</th>
                                        <th scope="col" class="text-center">Type</th>
                                        <th scope="col" class="text-center">Select</th>
                                        <th scope="col" class="text-center">Locked by User</th>
                                        <th scope="col" class="text-center">Status</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                    {% for lists in lists %}
                                    <tr>
                                        <th scope="row" class="text-center">{{ lists.id }}</th>
                                        <td class="text-center">{{ lists.Project }}</td>
                                        <td class="text-center">{{ lists.doc }}</td>
                                        <td class="text-center">{{ lists.TargetDate }}</td>
                                        <td class="text-center">{{ lists.docnum }}</td>
                                        <td class="text-center">{{ lists.type }}</td>
                                        <td class="text-center"><input class="form-check-input" type="radio"
                                                name="select1" id="selectradio" value="option1"></td>
                                        <td class="text-center">{{ lists.LockedUser }}</td>
                                        <td class="text-center">
                                            {% if lists.DStatus == "Available" %}
                                            <label class="badge badge-success">
                                                {% else %}
                                                <label class="badge badge-warning">
                                                    {% endif %}
                                                    {{ lists.DStatus }}</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    {% endfor %}
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                            <div class="text-right mr-5">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="nexttab" name="tab1btn"
                                    value="nxttab">Next</button>
                            </div>

                        </form>
```

Comment: the code will not enter the `elif` block because the first `if` is `True`. Put your conditions to save the data in the `if` block itself.

Comment: Thanks for your comment :) I understand your suggestion but i want that save to happen when that Next button is clicked. How can i achieve that if i move the save code to first `IF` please?

Answer (score 0):

I am just trying to re-factor your code, you should be able to pickup then.

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.urls import reverse

def form(request):
    projects = CreateProjects.objects.filter(Status=True)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.POST.get('tab1btn','') == 'nxttab':
            selval = ListProjDetails.objects.get(id=1)
            selval.Selected = True
            selval.LockedUser = request.user
            selval.save()  
            return redirect(reverse('name-of-the-view'))  # redirect to form.html   

        selectproject = request.POST.get('selectproject')
        searchprojlist = ListProjDetails.objects.filter(Project=selectproject)
        return render(request,'form.html',{'projects':projects,'lists': searchprojlist})
    else:
        lists = ListProjDetails.objects.all()
        return render(request,'form.html',{'projects':projects})
```

Comment: Hi Ejaz, this is ain't working... i have added image explaining what i am doing... any help would be great!! I think the issue is with the condition i have set at Javascript for moving to next tab, but i dont know how to resolve that